# fixed width and make it responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a ul with 3 li in it.
With display: flex, justify-content: space-between and some paddings and margins it looks exactly how I want it.

I have 2 more things, which im trying to do since hours but it doesnt work.

1. the li elements should have a fixed width. The fixed width works, but when i make the windows smaller, the width of the li elements shrinks to page size and they keep staying in the same row.
2. I want the width to be fixed, also when i make the windows smaller, and depending on the windows size the li elements should go in 2 or 3 rows (for mobile view)

I hope its quite understandable...

Here the my codes:

```css
.content-wrapper {
    ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 1em;

        li {
            margin-right: 2.5em;
            width: 350px;
            max-width: 350px;
        }
        li:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
         }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h1 class="content-title">
                        Über die Zahnarztpraxis
                    </h1>
                    <p class="content-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1 class="content-title">Öffnungszeiten</h1>
                    <p class="content-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1 class="content-title">Kontakt</h1>
                    <p class="content-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: now with code, sorry :)

Comment: and with min-width it worked!! thx
just remeaning the question, how they jump in different rows when i smaller the windows

Comment: yeah I deleted the comment since you posted code, not sure what part you want to go to different rows.

Comment: So i have the 3 li's in the same row. when I go on "mobile" view, i would like the li elements in a column.

Comment: Actually you don't, I took code you provided and made html file of it, every li is in its own row.

Comment: It is a list after all, li.

Comment: Strange.. in the beginning every li was in its own row. Then with display: flex; and justify-content: space-between; they appear in the same row

Comment: I can not recreate that.

Comment: check here is the whole side https://radu-pied.vercel.app/

Comment: Posted an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your item to `min-width` as I suggested in comment.

And set your `flexbox` `.content-wrapper ul` items to `flex-wrap: wrap;`
This will stack/wrap them on different screen sizes.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
  color: #141414;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -2px #b8b8b8;
          box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -2px #b8b8b8;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #141414;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 80px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

header ul li a {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

header ul li a:hover {
  color: #f0853e;
}

header ul li a:focus {
  color: #f0853e;
}

header ul li.nav-links {
  margin: 0 .1em;
}

.header-image {
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.header-image img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: #f0853e;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

h1.content-title {
  color: #f0853e;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

p.content-text {
  color: #141414;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.content-wrapper ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 1em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content-wrapper ul li {
  margin-right: 2.5em;
  width: 350px;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.content-wrapper ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <a href="#" class="logo">Zahnarztpraxis Dr. Beuran</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-links">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-links">   
                        <a href="#">Dienstleistungen</a>
                    </liclass="nav-links">
                    <li class="nav-links">
                        <a href="#">Über uns</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-links">
                        <a href="#">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-links">
                        <a href="#">Standort</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-links">
                        <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-image">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="http://derderic.ch/project/img/home.jpg" alt="Home">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h1 class="content-title">
                        Über die Zahnarztpraxis
                    </h1>
                    <p class="content-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1 class="content-title">Öffnungszeiten</h1>
                    <p class="content-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1 class="content-title">Kontakt</h1>
                    <p class="content-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked :) Both my issues are solved, thank you very much ikiK for your help!

Comment: @derderic Glad it helped, and welcome to SO, please consider marking this answer as accepted and giving it an up-vote, people here among other things like getting points for there effort, also it marks this question as solved. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Put li's content in div element with dispaly inline-block and add it in li.